# Error starting mongrel on windows after using RubyInstaller 1.9.1 RC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, mongrel

I installed Ruby via the RubyInstaller 1.9.1 RC2 available from [rubyforge](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167&release_id=42563), updated gems, and installed rails.  Everything worked fine using webrick.  For fun, I installed mongrel using "gem install mongrel".  The installation went fine:

```
Successfully installed gem_plugin-0.2.3
Successfully installed cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0
Successfully installed mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32
3 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for gem_plugin-0.2.3...
Installing ri documentation for cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0...
Installing ri documentation for mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32...
Updating class cache with 1162 classes...
Installing RDoc documentation for gem_plugin-0.2.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32...
```

Now, when I start the webserver using "ruby script/server", I get the error:

"The program can't start because msvcrt-ruby18.dll is missing from your computer."

Then, webrick starts and runs normally.

I'm guessing its a issue using Rails 1.9 and mongrel expects 1.8?  (I'm new to rails and there is no real reason for me to use mongrel.. just poking around)

Comment: i uninstalled 1.9 and installed 1.8.x and everything works now.  i'll leave this open if anyone knows if 1.9 can't work with mogrel correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Mongrel 1.2.0.pre2 when using Ruby 1.9.  If you're upgrading to Ruby 1.9, you should also upgrade to Ruby 1.9.2 since Rails has issues with Ruby 1.9.1.

To install without bundler:

```
gem install mongrel --pre
```

In your gemfile:

```
gem 'mongrel', '1.2.0.pre2'
```